# Recovering colour code from splitting colour scheme gradient into n colours

Tags: color

I'd like to get a colour scheme gradient (e.g. `ColorData["TemperatureMap"]`), split the domain into n equidistant points, and then recover the colour codes (RGB or Hex) for the resulting n points.

Comment: Take a look at `Blend`.

Comment: And the documentation for `ColorData`, especially the properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Clear[g]
g[color_, n_] := 
 Table[ColorData[color][i], {i, 0, ColorData[color][[3, 2]], 1/n}]
List @@@ g["TemperatureMap", 10]

(*{{0.178927, 0.305394, 0.933501}, {0.33766, 0.466886, 
  0.942736}, {0.528934, 0.628452, 0.956059}, {0.748934, 0.803792, 
  0.97561}, {0.912556, 0.933111, 0.991522}, {0.984192, 0.987731, 
  0.911643}, {0.994726, 0.991128, 0.667358}, {0.977887, 0.93707, 
  0.368596}, {0.924921, 0.740045, 0.258448}, {0.867569, 0.491545, 
  0.211209}, {0.817319, 0.134127, 0.164218}}*)
```

Comment: Browsing this site, it seems the goal is always to avoid using `Table`.  In that spirit, this does the same thing:  `List @@@ ColorData["TemperatureMap"] /@ Subdivide[1, 10]`